# Rails, accepts_nested_attributes_for has_many: through with build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I know there is bunch of similar question here, but neither helped me.

I have 3 models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_option_types
   has_many :option_types, through: :product_option_types
end

class OptionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_option_types
    has_many :products, through: :product_option_types
end

class ProductOptionType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :option_type
end
```

Table OptionType is predefined with following:

[image]

Now when creating new Product i need to populate also table product_option_types with product_id and option_type id: Here is the design of product_option_types table:

[image]

Far as i know i need accepts_nested_attributes_for in Product model to refference product_option_types, so in product model i need following **?**

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_option_types, allow_destroy: true
```

Before rendering new.html.erb then i need to build product_option_types on the following way **?**

```
@product = Product.new
@product.product_option_types.build(position: 1)
```

In the view new.html.erb i'm using collection_select to display option_types:

```
<%= f.fields_for :product_option_types do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :option_type_id, "Options" %>
    <%= builder.collection_select :option_type_id, OptionType.all(order: 'name ASC'), 
                                  :id, :name, { prompt: "Select option..."} %>
<% end %>
```

Finally in the crate action of product controller i must permit also association attributes like:

`permited = params[:product].permit(product_option_types_attributes: [:option_type_id])`

**So main question is, did i set up accepts_nested_attributes_for, build, collection_select and associations correctly?**

+: When im building associoation with parameters like:

```
@product.product_option_types.build(position: 1)
```

**Then to pass that information(position: 1) to create action i must use hidden_field in form?**

Comment: To your first question: well, does it work? If not, what happens instead? To your second question, yes, you need the `hidden_field` to pass the position along - or if it's not going to be modified anyway, you could simply set in in your `create` action instead of in `new`.

Comment: Is that really big problem?

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding the data you are interested in is OptionType.
So why not working with data instead of the relation.

```
 Product.first.option_types
```

is more interesting than the relation table.

Change from product_option_types to option_types.